# Request a phrase similar to "flag planting"?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, idiom-request

I am looking for a phrase to convey the activity in such a scenario:

I found a very interesting question on StackOverflow but know I cannot provide a satisfying answer at that moment. I was too busy to do some research on it and write an elaborate answer but I wanted to write a sketchy one and flesh it into a detailed one later when time permits.

I think, flag planning which was used in [this case](https://www.facebook.com/yann.lecun/posts/10154498539442143), would not be a good match here:

> Posting on ArXiv is good, flag planting notwithstanding.

In Chinese we call it "占个坑" which means literally to occupy a pit latrine but don't really need to poop right off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single word that describes this idea is [**placeholder**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placeholder):

> **1** : a person or thing that occupies the position or place of another person or thing
>
> // The bill would empower the governor to appoint a *placeholder* to a vacant U.S. Senate seat, to serve through the next general election cycle.
>   — John Sharp
>
> // The result was that the legislation represented little more than a *placeholder* to put the budget before a conference committee . . .
>   — Carl Ingram

In your sentence:

> Posting on ArXiv is good, *placeholders* notwithstanding.

Or (if actually posting one):

> This is just a *placeholder* for my eventual answer.